# How can I make my spaceship stop looking like Christmas?

Tags: warframe

A long time ago <strike>in a galaxy far, far away</strike>, I bought some Christmas decorations from the ingame market.  Naturally, I immediately decked out my ship and then promptly forgot all about it.

Now, <strike>two years</strike> some length of time later, I want a new look.  However, there's one tiny detail: I've forgotten how to take down the Christmas decorations.  Looking through the market and through the decoration menus provided me with no hints.

How do I take off the Christmas decorations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be quite simple, though not at all obvious to me.

Go to `esc->equipment->inventory` and look for "Festive Interior Decorations." Sell it. You will be refunded the 1 credit they likely cost, and they will go away.

Comment: I didnt refunded mine. There's an option where you can select festive events skins, and of course none of them.